# Google maps Marker Clustering with large (10,000+) GeoJSON?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, geojson

I'm trying to display some markers on a map of the UK, however as there are over 10,000, I'm trying to use the marker clustering utility to make it look less packed. I'm not sure how to make the clustering utility use coordinates from the GeoJSON file. The google guide only shows how to add in your own markers, not how to get them from a GeoJSON. Below is what I've tried so far:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.slideupmap);
    ...
    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, getMap());

    getMap().setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
    getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

    try {
        readItems();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Problem reading list of markers.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void readItems() throws JSONException, IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ukgeojson4102015);
    List<MyItem> items = new MyItemReader().read(inputStream);
    mClusterManager.addItems(items);
}
```

As such, I am always getting the "Problem reading list of markers" toast.

Below is the MyItem Class:

```
public class MyItem implements ClusterItem {
    private final LatLng mPosition;

    public MyItem(double lat, double lng) {
        mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    }

    @Override
    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return mPosition;
    }
}
```

**Where I'm coming stuck is what to put in the MyItemReader class**. The google one (below) is for a JSON file with 'lat' and 'lng' values:

```
public class MyItemReader {
    private static final String REGEX_INPUT_BOUNDARY_BEGINNING = "\\A";

    public List<MyItem> read(InputStream inputStream) throws JSONException {
        List<MyItem> items = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
        String json = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter(REGEX_INPUT_BOUNDARY_BEGINNING).next();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
            double lat = object.getDouble("lat");
            double lng = object.getDouble("lng");
            items.add(new MyItem(lat, lng));
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

In contrast, the GeoJSON data is in this format:

```
{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-5.12763, 51.95974],
            "is_accurate": true
        },
        "properties": {
        "    id": 30088,
            "inscription": "Some inscription"
        }
    }
```

The lat and lng values here are given under 'coordinates'. I'm assuming I need to tell MyItemReader to read these coordinates but I'm not sure how to do it.

Does anyone know what I'm supposed to put there? This is my first time working with GeoJSON data...

Answer (score 0):

If you need help parsing GeoJSON try using this library: https://github.com/cocoahero/android-geojson

Since you already have a JSONObject in your for loop, you'll just need to call GeoJSON.parse on it to get an object you can then read the coordinates from. (Alternatively you can write your own parsing code - based on your question though you might have an easier time using the library instead)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I don't think the problem is an inability to parse the GeoJSON, I'm trying to figure out how to make it usable in the MyItemReader class.

Comment: ```double lat = object.getDouble("lat");``` and ```double lng = object.getDouble("lng");``` are not going to work for what you're trying to do then - there are no JSON properties with the name "lat" or "lng" in the JSON you are trying to read. You'll want to instead change it to getJSONObject("geometry") and then call getJSONArray("coordinates") to get the coordinate array out of it. Then on the array you can call getDouble(0/1) to extract the lat/lng values.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I've been trying it the way you suggested but I can't quite figure out how to do this. So are you saying I should change the myitemreader class so it does the two steps you mentioned before doing the double lat/double lng functions? Are you able to provide an example or point me to some documentation/tutorial which can explain this in more detail?

Comment: If your JSON looks like what you had in the original question, then this code snippet should work:  `final JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            final JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
            final JSONObject geometry = object.getJSONObject("geometry");
            final JSONArray coordinates = geometry.getJSONArray("coordinates");
            double lat = coordinates.getDouble(0);
            double lng = coordinates.getDouble(1);
            items.add(new MyItem(lat, lng));
        }
        return items;`

Comment: Note that this will work only if the input does not contain any issues and would require error handling for cases where you have valid GeoJSON which does not match the described input (each object having a Point geometry)

Comment: Hi thank you so much for all your help so far. I've done it how you said, but it's showing the toast "problem reading list of markers". The current data I'm using has coordinates in this format: "coordinates": [-5.12763, 51.95974, 0.0]. The 0.0 is the same for each one. Is the code not working because I have to account for the 0.0 or is it something else?

Comment: I just deleted all the 0.0's and it still isn't working, I guess it's something else...

Comment: No, since the code is only getting first and second element out of the coordinates array any additional elements should be ignored. Can you get the exact exception message/stack trace?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I couldn't get the stacktrace and couldn't figure it out so I just changed my approach and decided not to use marker clustering.